# html mailto always need to open in outlook

Tags: html

In my application user can share the link via mail, for mail share I have implemented the mailto.

it's opening perfectly when the user has configured the default mail is outlook in their os (Windows8).

But if they the had set the default mail option as chrome or other option, outlook is not opening (Expected).

But i want to open always the mailto in outlook is there any configuration for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: User has  outlook, but configured different option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a preferred client in `mailto:` cause it's an user related OS setting.

If no particular email client is configured in the browser, then it should open the default one. This is generally a browser setting, though; e.g., in Firefox under Preferences -> Applications for "mailto".

Some users may not have Outlook, e.g. OS X users or mobile ones.